# WPF, MouseDown on and around Image

Tags: wpf, image, grid

I have a problem with the MouseDown event on an Image in WPF. The Image is in the cell of a Grid. Depending on the actually displayed image, the Image control will change its size within the grid cell. The MouseDown event will, of course, only fire when clicking on the Image, but not if I click anywhere around the Image (within the Image's grid cell). How can I make my event fire always when clicking within the grid cell, so my clickable area won't change all the time as I go through images? This can probably be solved with some control filling out the grid cell and containing the Image, but I can't figure out what to use.

Comment: Rectangle with transparent fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack controls on top of one another in a panel like a grid. This remains true for a "cell" of a grid.
Contents of grids or grid cells will usually expand to fill if you don't set height and width of them.
The order you declare ui in XAML defines it's z-index. Later ones are on top of previous ones.

Meaning that if you do:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="1"
           Height="30"
           Width="30"
           />
    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" 
               Grid.Column="1"/>
```

The rectangle will be on top of the image but you can't see it because it's fill is transparent. It will fill the cell it's in.
You can of course easily check that by setting the fill to a colour temporarily.

If that doesn't suit for some reason, you could put the rectangle behind the image and set IsHitTestVisible="False" on the image. When you click on the image you will not "Hit" it but instead click the rectangle.

When you click around the image you will click the rectangle with either approach.
Handle click of the rectangle.

Comment: I had tried that one, but it wouldn't work. Tried it again after your answer and saw that I specifically work with the event's sender, so that was the problem. Thanks!